# Why I getting an "Expression always true" warning?

Tags: c#

It's code where warning arises:

```
public async Task<Metadata> GetFolderAsync(string strDirectoryPathName, dynamic varKnownFolder = null)
{
    using (await _FolderPathToInfoMapSync.EnterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        Metadata objFolder;
        string strPathName = strDirectoryPathName;
        if (varKnownFolder == null)
        {
            objFolder = await _Storage.Client.Files.GetMetadataAsync(strPathName);
        }
        else
        {
            //Here warning arises
            if (varKnownFolder != null) _FolderPathToInfoMap.Add(strDirectoryPathName, varKnownFolder);
            else objFolder = null;
        }
    }
    return objFolder;
}
```

I mean reason for this is a varKnownFolder in method signature, but I don't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: You get "Expression always true" on `varKnownFolder != null` because the expression `varKnownFolder != null` is always true! :)

Comment: It's best what I heard forever. Thanks =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your code enters the first else block it means that `(varKnownFolder == null)` was evaluated to false.

So the second check is useless  as `varKnownFolder`  could never be null in this block.

```
public async Task<Metadata> GetFolderAsync(string strDirectoryPathName, dynamic varKnownFolder = null)
{
     using (await _FolderPathToInfoMapSync.EnterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
     {
           Metadata objFolder;
           string strPathName = strDirectoryPathName;

           if (varKnownFolder == null)
           {
               // This would happen if varKnownFolder is null 

               objFolder = await _Storage.Client.Files.GetMetadataAsync(strPathName);
           }
           else
           {
               // The code enters HERE BECAUSE varKnownFolder is not null

               if (varKnownFolder != null) // <-- So this check is useless
                   _FolderPathToInfoMap.Add(strDirectoryPathName, varKnownFolder);
               else 
                  objFolder = null;
            }

            return objFolder;
      }

}
```

Also, it means that you could replace it with this :

```
public async Task<Metadata> GetFolderAsync(string strDirectoryPathName, dynamic varKnownFolder = null)
{
     using (await _FolderPathToInfoMapSync.EnterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
     {
           Metadata objFolder = null;
           string strPathName = strDirectoryPathName;

           if (varKnownFolder == null)
           {
               objFolder = await _Storage.Client.Files.GetMetadataAsync(strPathName);
           }
           else
           {
               // The code enters HERE BECAUSE varKnownFolder is not null
               _FolderPathToInfoMap.Add(strDirectoryPathName, varKnownFolder);
            }

            return objFolder;
      }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to initialize `objFolder` to `null` in the last code snippet?

Comment: objFolder is not readen in this piece of code. So initializing `objFolder` to null is useless.

Comment: It is returned as the result of the function.

Comment: Right !! So it should be initialized to null. Edit made. Anyway the scope in the OP is wrong

Comment: True. Technically you don't even need the variable, the `if` could just `return await ...` and then you can drop the `else` and `return null` there. But that's probably partially personal preference so let's stick to the OP's code as closely as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are checking the inverse of the same condition within a block that has already been asserted by the outer if statement. Logically your code is the equivalent of...

```
if(x==false)
{

}
else // x must be true here
{
    if(x==true) { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (varKnownFolder == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //You already know it is not null (because of the "if" check)
            if (varKnownFolder != null)
        }
```

Your "if" statement checks if you have a null object.
Inside your "else", `varKnownFolder` can't be null.

> I mean reason for this is a varKnownFolder in method signature

Nope, the `varKnownFolder = null` inside method signature just means that, if you call this method without `varKnownFolder`, it will be null.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is clever and spotted your mistake, then it warned you about it.

```
 if (varKnownFolder == null)
 {
     // null
 }
 else
 {
     // *** NOT null ***
     if (varKnownFolder != null) _FolderPathToInfoMap.Add(strDirectoryPathName, varKnownFolder);
     else objFolder = null;
}
```

So what you wrote is equivalent to

```
  if (varKnownFolder == null)
  {
      objFolder = await _Storage.Client.Files.GetMetadataAsync(strPathName);
  }
  else
  {
      _FolderPathToInfoMap.Add(strDirectoryPathName, varKnownFolder);
  }
```